# Proving $\int_{[0,1] \times [0,1]} 1_S$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $S = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | x$ rational, $0<x<1$, and write $x = p/m$ in lowest form, $y = k/m, k = 1, \cdots, m-1 \}$, i.e. $S=\bigcup_{m\in\Bbb N}\{(p/m,\,k/m)|k,\,p\in\{1,\,\cdots,\,m-1\},\,(p,\,m)=1\}$. I am trying to prove that $\int_{[0,1] \times [0,1]} 1_S$ does not exist, where $1_S(x,y) = 1$ if $(x,y) \in S$ and $1_S(x,y) = 0$ otherwise.

I thought the set of discontinuities of $1_S$ is the set $S$ itself, and since $S$ is a countable set, $1_S$ is integrable. Can someone point out where I'm wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a Riemann integral?

Comment: Yes. This is a Riemann integral indeed.

Comment: Both $S$ and $[0,1]\times[0,1]\setminus S$ are dense in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, and so every lower Riemann sum you take will be $0$ (no matter the partition), and any upper Riemann sum you take will be $1$ (no matter the partition).Therefore the Riemann integral does not exist.  However, since $S$ is a countable set, the Lebesgue integral will be $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, both $S$ and $[0,1]^2\setminus S$ are dense in $[0,1]^2$, therefore the set of discontinuities of $1_S$ is $[0,1]^2$.

Density of $[0,1]^2\setminus S$ is easy and you seem already persuaded of that.

For density of $S$, let $(x,y)\in (0,1)^2$. Notice that for any $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a rational number $q$ in the form $\frac{n}{2^m}$ such that $\left\lvert q-\alpha\right\rvert<\varepsilon$. Also observe that we may find one such that $n$ is odd (and therefore such that $\frac{n}{2^m}$ is reduced) and, for all $N\in\Bbb N$, we may find one such that $m>N$. Putting all these together with the appropriate care, I state that for all $\alpha\in(0,1)$, for all $\varepsilon>0$ and for all $N\in\Bbb N$ there is some rational number $q\in(0,1)$ such that $\lvert q-\alpha\rvert<\varepsilon$ and such that there is some $m>N$ such that $2^mq$ is an odd natural number. And this is rather easy to prove.

Now, let $\varepsilon>0$ and consider $q_y=\frac{2n_y+1}{2^{m_y}}$ a rational number such as above obtained for $\alpha=y$ and $N=1$. Moreover, consider $q_x=\frac{2n_x+1}{2^{m_x}}$ a rational number obtained as above with $\alpha=x$ and $N=m_y$. Notice that $$q_y=\frac{2^{m_x-m_y}(2n_y+1)}{2^{m_x}}.$$

$2^{m_x-m_y}(2n_y+1)$ is a positive natural number because $m_x>m_y$ and, moreover, $2^{m_x-m_y}(2n_y+1)<2^{m_x}$ because $0<q_y<1$. Since $\frac{2n_x+1}{2^{m_x}}$ is reduced, we have that $(q_x,q_y)\in S$. Also, $$\lVert (q_x,q_y)-(x,y)\rVert\le \lvert q_x-x\rvert+\lvert q_y-y\rvert<2\varepsilon$$

This proves that $\overline S\supseteq(0,1)^2$, and therefore $\overline S=[0,1]^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! But I don't quite see how $q_y=\frac{2^{m_x-m_y}(2m_y+1)}{2^{n_x}}$. Could you show me how you derived that?

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics There was a typo it should have been $q_y=\frac{2^{m_x-m_y}(2n_y+1)}{2^{m_x}}$.